# JavaScript navigation to named hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have the following hyperlink:

```
<a name="top"></a>
```

My button looks like this:

```
<span id="listControl_1_ctl15" onclick="window.location='#top'" class="TextButton">
    <span class="button_left"></span>
    <span class="button_text">Bovenaan</span>
    <span class="button_right"></span>
</span>
```

My page doesn't navigate to the top section. Does anyone know why?

Comment: What you've quoted should work just fine (and does: http://jsbin.com/odamic) barring issues in something not quoted.

Comment: What browser are you testing this in. I just tried this in IE9, Firefox 8, and Chrome and it works fine.

Comment: I'm using IE9, but it falls back to the stupid quircks mode ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `window.location.hash` :

```
<span id="listControl_1_ctl15" onclick="window.location.hash='top'" class="TextButton">
    <span class="button_left"></span>
    <span class="button_text">Bovenaan</span>
    <span class="button_right"></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

put this on what you call the top:

```
<a name="top"></a>
```

and then you can use this to go to the link

```
<a href= "#top"> go to the top </a>
```

if you want to go to the top of the whole page you can use this also:

```
<a href = #> TOP! </a>
```

stefan.

Comment: Nice solution! But the given example is simplified. The real thing needs to use a span / JavaScript ;-).

Comment: ok, maybe you could add that to the question next time :). i hope you found a solution!

Answer (score 2):

You should use hash :

```
window.location.hash='top'
```